# Submit a form in a loop after click on the div containing it

Tags: jquery, forms, loops, html, click

I have a Form in a Div, itself in a loop. I'd like to submit the variable contained in the submit value depending on the Div clicked. But whatever Div created I'm clicking on, I always get the same result. I've tried with $(this).next('form') many others ways but nothing works.

HTML:

```
while (condition) {
    <div class="mail_summary">
        <form class="form_send_id" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_send_id" value="$variable">
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script>
    $(".mail_summary").click(function(){ 
        $('.form_send_id').submit();
    });  
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi, can you share more details what you're trying to do? are you generating the divs in the while condition? if yes then through which language? i feel your doing something wrong here. Please elaborate!

Comment: what u doing here buddy?

Comment: I do am generating the divs in the while condition. I have few information in them but I'd like the overall div to be clickable and not only specific information in it.

The fact is that I am close to the result but I have a selector problem I think because it do not send the good variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the `while` loop is not JavaScript, but the language you're working with to create your HTML and this `while` loop is creating more than one `div` containing its own form.

With that assumption, you can simply reference the event's target in your closure to get the right submission of your form, then do a little DOM traversal to the child form, like so:

```
$(".mail_summary").click(function(event){ 
    $(event.target).find('.form_send_id').submit();
});
```

If you are, for some reason, rendering your divs with JavaScript (I'm not sure how and I hope not), then your forms will be created in a way that event delegation will be needed.  To do this, you will need to give the event a delegate using jQuery's `on` method, like so:

```
$("body").on("click", ".mail_summary", function(event){ 
    $(event.target).find('.form_send_id').submit();
});
```

I hope that helps